# Make editor responsive during the loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a debugging utility and one feature is force hang the entire game in a short period.

Simple loop is perfect solution for me, however this also blocks Unity Editor.
This is a very obvious consequence but very annoying.

Is there any way to process editor events during custom loops?

```cs
void SleepEntireGame(int ms) {
  while( timeReached == false ) {
    // do nothing
    // because all i need is just hold the game in a short period.
    ;

    // I'm looking for something like this:
    UnityEditor.ProcessEvents();
  }
}
```

- Please don't recommend me any other GOOD way to pause the game. Thanks

Comment: Does your game run *in* the editor/ide? Or is it just consuming 100% cpu?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the preprocessor directive `UNITY_EDITOR`.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html
The conventional idea to pause a game is to have things depend on `Time.deltaTime` and set `Time.timeScale` to 0..

Comment: Just pausing a game is not a what I want. Entire execution has to be stopped for a while. CPU consumtion is not a consideration.
I know what I'm doing very well.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your loop on another thread and apply event delegation (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)) and register to the event handler in your editor class , whenever the loop finishes you will fire the event in you thread and your editor thread will be notified , you may add a loading text or progress bar to show the user that the app is working but like that the ui will stay responsive .

If you want to take it to its next level you can use the cancellation token (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads))  to be able to cancel the loop from continuation as well .

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bool variable to use in your update functions to stop functionality of your game and use a coroutine to do the wait thing.

```
IEnumerator SleepEntireGame(int ms)
{
    sleepGame = true;
    while(timeReached == false)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    sleepGame = false;
}
```